# Are Cryo-EM questions on topic on biology.SE?

Tags: discussion

As some of you may have notice, the [3D-em proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116061/3d-em) on Area51 got quite a number of followers (142 currently).

It is

> for scientists doing **biology** 3D electron microscopy, from sample preparation to image processing, including data acquisition.

Since even so many followers may not be enough to get it to public beta, I was thinking that perhaps a tag on Biology.SE could be used as an alternative. I just [asked about it](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27769/alternative-3d-em-tag-on-biology-se) in a discussion on the proposal.

Just to make sure: am I right that example questions from that proposal would be on topic here?

Comment: You might want to check out the bioinformatics.SE site, they formed out of a similar proposal. A lot of those questions would be on-topic here (as are a lot of the bioinformatics ones), except for the ones that are *purely technical questions with no underlying biology*. In my opinion, "My protein aggregates on cryo grids but seems fine in negative stain. Why does this happen and how can I overcome this?" is an acceptable technical question here, whereas "How do I create a mask for a region of my protein?" is probably not.

Comment: I would add that biology.SE is a pretty small community, so it's tough to get answers to high-end questions here. It's simply that biology is a hugely diverse field and each of us is probably the one and only expert in our field here. I'd also wonder, why a cryo-EM specific stack? Why not something more broad covering all EM? Or even biological microscopy/histology in general?

Comment: @BryanKrause cryo-EM is closer to macromolecular cystallography than to histology. It's clear that some questions may not get answers. But if technical questions about experimental methods in biology are not on-topic -- this is a bigger problem.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification, see - not my field of biology. :) I think the types of questions that we were rejecting here that led to the creation of bioinformatics.SE were the repeated questions about software packages, etc - sort of like how R programming questions are not on-topic at stats.SE unless there is an underlying question about the stats.

Comment: I think you summed it up with this statement: *"I suppose that CryoEM questions would be on-topic and welcomed on Biology.SE. On the other hand, attracting experts to a more general-purpose site would be more difficult."* If there is not enough interest in a cryo-EM site, perhaps you need to expand the scope, as BryanKrause suggested, to include all of microscopy or, perhaps, molecular biology. I would certainly be interested in the latter proposal.

Comment: @canadianer I agree, but I doubt if even a molecular biology proposal would make it. So as the next step in expanding the scope we come to Biology.SE. BTW I see that splitting biology was discussed here: https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/would-there-be-more-specific-se-branches-communities-for-some-broad-branches-o